# How to add a class when reaching a certain element at the top of the page and delete it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(window).on('scroll', function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() >= $('#element').offset().top){
            $('.menu').addClass('addclass');
        }
    });
});
```

It adds `addclass` to the menu when reaching `id = "element"` at the top of the page and scrolling further to the bottom.

But how to remove `addclass` when `id = "element"` is again below the top of the pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use toggleClass or removeClass:)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(window).on('scroll', function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() >= $('#element').offset().top){
            $('.menu').addClass('addclass');
        }
        else 
        {
            $('.menu').toggleClass('addclass');
            //or use $('.menu').removeClass('addclass');
        }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do the reverse:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

        $(window).on('scroll', function(){
            if($(window).scrollTop() < $('#element').offset().top){
              $('.menu').removeClass('addclass');
            }
          });
    });
```